# An equation involving fractional covering number of hypergraphs

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, graph-theory, hypergraph

Let $\mathcal{H}=(S,\mathcal{X})$ be a hypergraph, where $S = \{ s_1, \ldots, s_n \}$, and $\mathcal{X} = \{ X_1, \ldots, X_m \}$.

The *dual* hypergraph $\mathcal{H}^*$ of $\mathcal{H}$ is the hypergraph with vertex set $X$ and hyperedge set $\mathcal{S}$ with
$X = \{ x_1, \ldots, x_m \}$ and $\mathcal{S} = \{ S_1, \ldots, S_n \}$, such that $x_j \in S_i$ if and only if $s_i \in X_j$ (in $\mathcal{H}$).

Also by $\overline{\mathcal{H}}$ we denote the hypergraph $(S,\{S \setminus X~|~X \in\mathcal{X}\})$.

A *$t$-fold covering* of hypergraph $\mathcal{H}=(S,\mathcal{X})$ is a multiset $\{ X_1, \ldots, X_j \}$ (where each $X_j \in \mathcal{X}$) with the property that each $s \in S$ is in at least $t$ of the $X_i's$. 
The smallest cardinality (least $j$) of such a multiset is called the *$t$-fold covering number* of $\mathcal{H}$ and is denoted $k_t(\mathcal{H})$.

The *fractional covering number* of $\mathcal{H}$ is $k_f(\mathcal{H}) = \lim_\limits{t \rightarrow \infty}\frac{k_t(\mathcal{H})}{t}$

My question is whether the following fact is known in the literature?

**Fact.** For any hypergraph $\mathcal{H}$, 
$$
\frac{1}{k_f(\mathcal{H}^*)} + \frac{1}{k_f(\overline{\mathcal{H}})} = 1.
$$